# PHP - how to add array values in mysql query and retrieve single data from each category

Tags: php

i have a following array output...i want to use this array value in mysql query.

**Output of array value:**

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 144 [category_id] => 144 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 98
[category_id] => 98 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 146 [category_id] => 146 ) [3] => 
Array ( [0] => 142 [category_id] => 142 ) ) 

Array Value : 144 98 146 142
```

**i want Sql query to get four records related to above ids (144 98 146 142)**

```
$Sql_array = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product_table")
```

Thanks for your help....

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM product_table WHERE id IN (144,98,146,142);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM product_table WHERE category_id IN (1,2,3,4)
```

in your example

```
$Sql_array = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product_table WHERE category_ID IN (".join(',',$array).")")
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you could use a loop like so

```
(string)$select;
foreach($array as $k){
 $select.= $k[0].",";
}
$select = substr_replace($select ,"",-1);
$query = "SELECT * FROM product_table WHERE id IN (".$select.")";
```